# How to link pages of menu in laravel 5.8.0

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I am facing a problem in the menu bar which doesn't show result correctly. I am sharing a few lines.

**index.blade.php: -**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Easy Service</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Home </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="services">Services</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="contact">Contact</a>
      </li>

      <li class="es">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is another file.

**web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});
Route::get('/services', function () {
    return view('services');
});
```

When I open up the pages from the home page by clicking the links, the output is correct but when I open up the links through other pages then home page link is not working.
If I put `(/index)` in *web.php* file, then it worked, but I don't want to show my home page link in URL with `(/index)`.
It is only by opening with showing the name with URL after a slash (/).

How can I link home page without showing URL on the browser?

[Home Page with Empty slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKbqz.jpg)
[image: Home Page with Empty slash]
[About Page with Non-empty slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4F2i.jpg)
[image: About Page with Non-empty slash]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use empty `href` attribute in `<a>` if it should reference to index page use `<a href="/">` because when `href` is not filled link will follow to current page. Or you can use named routes in Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-named-routes